# Why is the reputation numerical value is a link on the parent site, but not on meta?

Tags: support

I mean that number that shows your reputation at the top of the screen (between your name and the orange "badge" icon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually accrue reputation on meta. The number shown is your rep on the parent site. It's not linked because the table of reputation limits (which is where the link points to on the parent site) is irrelevant on meta.

Comment: "It's not linked because the table of reputation limits ... is irrelevant on meta" - I see. However, it's a bit inconvenient when I want to "jump" to that table directly from meta.